# URL to InputStream with Java

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, inputstream, domparser

I'm using Android Studio to write an application that should parse data from a xml-file (with the DOM-Parser) which is available from this url: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

Momentarily it is only possible to retrive the data from the xml-document "file.xml" which is stored in my project.

```
TextView tv;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    XMLDOMParser parser = new XMLDOMParser();
    AssetManager manager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream;

    try {
       
        stream = manager.open("file.xml");
        Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Tag");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

            list.add(parser.getValue(e, "Value"));
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        tv.setText(e1.toString());
    }
    ;


    }

}
```

What can I do that my InputStream named "stream" contains the xml-document from my url?

Answer (score 0):

XMLDOMParser is actually a standard add on used in JAVA and Android Studio does not have it loaded. Android studio has chosen to use XMLPullParser instead. Here is a link on how to use it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser

Comment: I have tried it with the Pull-Parser but it still doesn't work. What made I wrong? 
          `InputStream istream = new URL("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml").openStream();

            XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,false);
            parser.setInput(istream,null);`